# Weird crash in AIR application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash

I have a crash that only happens with the installed application I can't make it cvrash in the IDE(Flash Builder debug or run option)

After a long time of commenting and uncomenting code I found the problem and I am posting the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       xmlns:ns="generic_components.*"
                       creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            //import core.Logger;

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

            protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                //Logger.init();
            }
            public static function humanFromCamelCase(txt:String):String{

                var res:String=txt.charAt(0);
                //Logger.write("camel case for "+txt);
                for (var i:int=1;i<txt.length;i++) 
                {
                    //  Logger.write("camel iter "+i);
                    var c:String=txt.charAt(i);
                    //Logger.write("camel char is "+c);
                    if(c==c.toUpperCase())
                    {
                        res=res+" "+c;  
                    }
                    else
                        res=res+c;
                }

                return res;
            }


            protected function test_clickHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                Alert.show(humanFromCamelCase("CompanyId"));

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>
    <s:Button id="test" label="TEST" click="test_clickHandler(event)"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Also see a web sample here http://ploscariu.com/crash/TestWeb.html  (may be not there in the future)

What is weird about this crash:
1 I have no idea what happens

2 The usual crash handler in the player does not show up

3 is not crashing in the development enviroment IDE

4 if i uncomment those Logger.write  then the code works on my machine fine(it could not work on all machines), the Logger.write writes the sting in a file and is placed in another project swf (I did not included the logger code)
I a, assuming that the call to Logger.write can cause a delay or something similar

It is something wrong in my code or the player is buggy? or the compiler??
Any ideas?

Edit:
-is not the logger i use since the error happens when I am not using it like in the sample code or page, no logger the app it crashes

-i get no dialog from Flash with a crash report

Comment: What sort of a log-target are you using? If you're logging to a file on disk, you may have hit a security sandbox issue with the installed application (which probably will have a stricter security setting).

Comment: Hi, the logger fixes the issue here, is a custom logger, I am assuming that it could add a delay or something. the logger is not the issue, you can reproduce the problem without the logger

Comment: @Neil  is not the Logger the sample code and the web page do not use it and do not include it, i updated the question with this details

Comment: What is the usual "crash handler" in the player?  If I run your web sample; I see the standard Flash Player error popup.  You get a stack overflow error: "VerifyError: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred. at TestWeb/test_clickHandler() at TestWeb/__test_click()" You won't see that if you don't have the debug version of the player installed.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com  the error is in the method  humanFromCamelCase  but why? it seems to be a crash in the FlashPlayer. I have the debug version but I am making an AIR application so I am not setup for web, in my debug envirnment Flash Builder the code runs properly

Comment: @simion314 I'm not sure; the code looks solid.  There is no obvious reason it would create that error.  I'd post this as a bug in the Adobe bug base.

Comment: Did you try `var res:String = txt.length ? txt.charAt(0) : '';`?

Answer (score 2):

This is so incredibly odd!!!!  I have NO idea why this happening (yet)... but I have a workaround:

Instead of `res=res+c`, use `res+=c`:

```
public static function humanFromCamelCase(txt:String):String{

    var res:String=txt.charAt(0);
    for (var i:int=1;i<txt.length;i++) 
    {
        var c:String=txt.charAt(i);
        if(c === c.toUpperCase())
        {
            res += " " + c;  
        }
        else
            res += c;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: the workaround  works, the problem is what is the actual problem so I can be sure this iwill not happen again in other parts of the code, and this workaround could not work in the future or in other players(i am thinking the code change is so small the a future version of the compiler could "fix" the work around and trigger the error. I hope you can find the cause. Thx for your time.

Comment: I spent forever trying to figure it out... I am convinced it is a compiler error.  I'm looking into it further (I sent it to some people at Adobe to look at)... this is the weirdest error I've seen in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you're having an error, however, I would replace the function with this instead:

```
public static function humanFromCamelCase(txt:String):String{
    return txt.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(/^ /, "");
}
```

Haven't tested it, but you get the idea.  This is a much simpler and faster approach.

I also thought of another way:

```
public static function humanFromCamelCase(txt:String):String{
    return txt.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ');
}
```

Comment: As an added comment, there has been reports of memory management problems with Flex 4.6 and Flash 11.3.  I haven't seen them myself, but I heard it through the apache flex mailing list.